# HTML CSS WHITE BAR & HORIZONTAL BAR

Tags: html, css, space

Why is at my Website [link](http://mikroboards.de/) between the navigation elements a space and why is a whitebar under the header image?

`margin`and `padding`is set to 0 everywhere i thought. No plan...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to say

Comment: WHy are there the spaces?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927890/whitespace-causing-divs-to-stack-in-pure-css?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image inside a div

```
<div style="height:350px; width:800px;"><img src="/assets/header.png"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, and the other spaces between navigation elements?

Comment: Which other navigation elements ?

Answer (score 0):

try to set "line-height: 0px" in your CSS files for that element

Comment: and the navigation elements?

Comment: set line height or try to set content: ""

Answer (score -1):

for fixing the navigation:

```
nav li {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The second white space, I believe, is caused by the header (h1 tag)

## Wilkommen